# Matlab for loop failing after first iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a uni assignment on numerically calculating the sine and cosine of a given theta. The program I have written in Matlab only works if I give it a single value of theta rather than using a for loop which is what I need to do. Here is the code:

```
x_old = 1;
y_old = 0;
for theta = 0:pi/3:2*pi
    theta_i = theta;
    for i = 1:16
        phi_i = atan(10^(-i+1));
        n_i = floor(theta_i/phi_i);
        for j=1:n_i
            x_new = x_old - y_old*10^(-i+1);
            y_new = y_old + x_old*10^(-i+1);
            x_old = x_new;
            y_old = y_new;
        end
        theta_i = theta_i - n_i*phi_i;
    end
    Sin = y_old/sqrt(x_old^2 + y_old^2);
    Cos = x_old/sqrt(x_old^2 + y_old^2);
    disp([theta, Sin, Cos])
end
```

end here is the output:

```
 0     0     1

1.0472    0.8660    0.5000

2.0944    0.0000   -1.0000

3.1416   -0.0000    1.0000

4.1888   -0.8660   -0.5000

5.2360    0.0000   -1.0000

6.2832    0.0000   -1.0000
```

The code above fails after pi/3 but if I modify the first for loop to any single value rather than a range, it works perfect. What is wrong with my code? How do I fix this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: you have displayed the values using `disp([theta, Sin, Cos])`. And the `for` loop runs till `theta = 2*pi`. from the last value of `theta` i.e `6.2832` i think the `for` loop is working fine. whats wrong with the results? what results do you expect?

Comment: The loop seems to be working fine, yes, it is displaying the correct theta. but for each theta I'm getting incorrect corresponding sine and cosine values. Column 2 is for sine values and column 3 is for cosine values. As you can see in the 1st and 2nd row, i.e. theta = 0 and pi/3, I am getting correct sine and cosine values. However, after that, it fails. Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: Also, if I modify line 3 of the code to:    for theta = "any value I coose"     The calculation works perfectly. It's as soon as I give a range of values to loop through it fails quickly after.

Comment: That's because you are modifying your `x_old` and `y_old` variable inside your loop. for single run, your `x_old` value and `y_old` value are `1` and `zero` respectively. but when you run as a loop, your value changes for every iteration in the loop.